# Volume and surface area calculation of intersecting cones

Tags: area, volume

I have a square lattice arrangement of cones: 3 rows of 33 cones, with a 6m centre to centre spacing in the horizontal and vertical direction. Each cone is 3.6m in height, 6.24m in base radius, and has an apex angle of 60° from the vertical. As such, there is a degree of intersection and overlapping between all the cones.

I would like to calculate the total surface area and the volume of all the cones, accounting for all the intersection and overlap, but can't seem to figure out an appropriate equation for this calculation.

Can anybody help?

Comment: What have you tried?  Where did you get tripped up?

Comment: I tried basic trigonometry, but couldn't get anywhere on that.... have been staring at this problem for the past few hours but have gotten nowhere.